# Duplicate and Randomize JUnit 4 test execution?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a suite of JUnit 4 tests. I'd like to run these in a randomized order, and run certain tests in the suite multiple times. JUnit 3 API seems a little friendlier to do this, but I run up against trouble when I need to use an @Before method.

Is there anyway to do the above in JUnit 4? My current approach with 3 was to read in all the tests (using the JUnit4 adapter class) into a List, duplicate and randomize as needed, and them execute the tests in the list. But this won't work when I need to share variables between the tests using @Before.

Although this is not generally the idea of unit testing, I'm actually just using JUnit as a convenient API: these are not actually unit tests, so I'm expecting the randomization to affect the results.

Comment: That is not the idea of unit tests. Each unit test should be completely independent of all others. If you have a test case which involves executing the operations of another test multiple times or executing the operations of different tests in a special order then you should do exactly that: create a new unit test which executes those operations or even call those test methods the way you need it. Adding random to unit tests is generally a bad thing. It means you don't really know what you are testing and the results might be random as well.

Comment: I should have added, I'm actually just using JUnit as a convenient API, but the purpose is not Unit tests really